# How to set up filter in logstash config file kubernetes with Date: component: level: message?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat, elk

I am setting up elk cluster with filebeat. I am trying to create filter in logstash config file with following format `(Date: component: level: message)`. But the filter is not working.

```
2021-08-17 18:57:33 component INFO msg

grok {
   match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}  %{DATA:component} %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel}  -%{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}" }
}
```

Comment: Hi!, please format your code with code fences to make the code readable. Goodluck 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

input:

```
2021-08-17 18:57:33 component INFO msg
```

grok pattern:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{DATA:component} %{LOGLEVEL:logLevel} %{GREEDYDATA:logMessage}
```

output:

```
{
  "timestamp": [
    [
      "2021-08-17 18:57:33"
    ]
  ],
  "YEAR": [
    [
      "2021"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHNUM": [
    [
      "08"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHDAY": [
    [
      "17"
    ]
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    [
      "18",
      null
    ]
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    [
      "57",
      null
    ]
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    [
      "33"
    ]
  ],
  "ISO8601_TIMEZONE": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ],
  "component": [
    [
      "component"
    ]
  ],
  "logLevel": [
    [
      "INFO"
    ]
  ],
  "logMessage": [
    [
      "msg"
    ]
  ]
}
```